# Как сделать удаление файлов по списку из Listbox?

Tags: delphi

Пример, в listbox загружен список файлов:

```
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\ts\1.txt
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\test2\2.mp3
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\file\backup\4.pdf
```

При нажатии на кнопку, нужно, все эти файлы - удалить.

Я пробовала вот так сделать, но так не удобно, поскольку, каждый раз, нужно выделять - путь к файлу и нажимать на кнопку.

```
DeleteFile(ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пройдитесь циклом по списку.

```
For i:=0 to ListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
begin
    DeleteFile(ListBox1.Items[i]);
end;
```

Comment: Сработало, только я так поняла что нужно добавить цыклу (-1), тое сть так ListBox1.Items.Count-1. Что бы не было ошибки List Index out of bounds(1).

Comment: Да, именно так.